# How to use last item in combo box vb.net

Tags: vb.net, indexing, combobox

Trying to create a program that takes user input and multiplies it by a value in a combo box, 1 to 9. The combo box must automatically increment by 1. Results are displayed in a List box. I got all of this to work, my problem is that when the combo box reaches the last value, it throws an error. How do I fix it so that when it reaches the last value it does not throw an error? 
combo box is populated on form load

```
Dim intUserInput As Integer
Dim outPut As Integer
intUserInput = TextBox1.Text
Try

    If intUserInput >= 1 Then
        outPut = intUserInput * ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        ListBox1.Items.Add(outPut)
        TextBox1.Clear()
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
    End If


Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
End Try
```

Comment: You should put `Option Strict On` at the top of the file and read [ask] and take the [tour] because we need the error message in the post not just `it throws an error`

Comment: Can you post your entire code for the form?

Comment: No, do not post the entire form.  The context for that code - the method it is located would be nice.

Comment: `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1`  That won't work.  Only increment it when you know you aren't on the last item.

Comment: Eventually you are going to run out of items in the index of the combobox if you don't put any logic in to stop that counter from increasing. Hence why "it throws an error" when you get to the last value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's throwing an error at you because you are trying to add past the index of the last item of the combo box. So you need to ensure that you don't add past that value. The following code should sort this problem, but I think you need more, particularly checking textbox is numeric (Look at [Integer.Tryparse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
Dim intUserInput As Integer
Dim outPut As Integer
intUserInput = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
Try
    If intUserInput >= 1 Then
        outPut = intUserInput * CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(outPut)
        TextBox1.Clear()
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
        End If
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
End Try
```